# How to scrape data from different websites?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, yaml

I'm trying to scrape product data from different ecommerce websites like Amazon, ebay and other. All of them has a similar pattern, big image showing the product, a title for the product, price...

Actually i'm using the next code with Python, BeatifulSoup library and YML file for each ecommerce (YML for Amazon, YML for ebay...):

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests
import json
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('url', help='Amazon Product Details URL')
# Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('./aliexpress.yml')

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
# Download the page using requests
args = argparser.parse_args()
r = requests.get(args.url, headers=headers)
# Pass the HTML of the page and create
data = e.extract(r.text)
# Print the data
print(json.dumps(data, indent=True))
```

It's ok for the first step of scraping, but what happens if i don't know the ecommerce url that is going to be passed and i don't have an YML file preconfigured for it. The scraper will return null, because is not possible to find css selectors.

```
{
 "name": null,
 "price": null,
 "image": null
}
```

What is the way to create a scraper that is able to find the data in a smart way, finding by itself the proper selectors to extract?

Comment: The website may look same in apperance but structure is always different. Try making a scraper for particular website according to its design :)

Comment: So, for example, if we want to detect a big image as the main photo, are you meaning to detect the image with a specific dimensions for a big image, instead of detect the ccs selector of the big image?

Comment: Not that ; Check the html code and then code accordingly

Comment: I don't understand. What can i check in the html code that could be a patron for all the shops? I need reliability taking information (title, photo, price, description). But each page is different.

Comment: I always suggest this video to anyone who wants to learn python scraping https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI&t=51s